# How do I detect that the Windows Mobile transitioned to continuum mode?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone, win-universal-app

Is there a way to detect that Windows Mobile 10 transitioned into continuum mode?

The message-box on Windows Phone does not look anything like the one on Desktop and our designers want parity. I want to write our own version, but I only want it to work on Phone - I want the default one on desktop or when the app transitions to continuum on phone.

Any ideas?

I could not find anything on the web nor find any API that allows me to detect it.

Comment: I think you can still run apps on the phone and have continuum mode running at the same time.  So I don't think there would be a event for transiioning

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but I don't think there is an API for Continuum. The idea of Continuum for Phone is that you're going from a fixed display size to something that is variable. The best way to detect this would be using the Visual State Triggers or checking if the size of the window has changed.

By also checking that the device family, `AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily`, is `Windows.Mobile`, you'll know that you're using a phone device which is currently in the Continuum mode.

Comment: You can't be 100% sure that app's window is showing on a separate screen and not on a phone's just by it's size.

Comment: This is true @khamitimur but when creating a universal Windows application, you should be considering the adaptiveness of your application. Knowing the DeviceFamily gives you the choice to do something with that mobile family at a given screen resolution. This is when you start combining state triggers. I'll update my answer with some XAML to make my answer a little clearer

Comment: Sometimes there is a real need to know if app is showing on 30" display and not on 5" on a phone in landscape. Like when you need to properly display `TextBox`.

Comment: Also I'm considering for now use `DeviceFamily` and physical display size (scale * size). For now Continuum uses whole screen, so it'll work 99.9% of time.

Answer (score 1):

To detect if app is running in Continuum mode you'll need to check two things: `DeviceFamily` and `UserInteractionMode`.

```
public static bool IsInContinuum()
{
   if (DeviceFamily() == DeviceFamilyType.Mobile && UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView().UserInteractionMode == UserInteractionMode.Mouse)
      return true;

   else
      return false;
}
```

Quote from [this post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/12/07/optimizing-apps-for-continuum-for-phone/):

"With Continuum, “touch” will always be returned when your app is on the mobile device, and “mouse” will always be returned when your app is on the connected display."

So you'll need to check if app runs in Continuum in `SizeChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

Due to MSDN Documentation Below, 
There's no spesific trigger for Windows 10 Mobile continuum feature detection.

[Continuum for Universal Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn917883(v=vs.85).aspx)

In order to find a solution on Mobile Apps, you can benefit from adaptive UI, you can check the app via screen resolution change `Window.Current.SizeChanged`, then you can combine with Device family `AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily` to check if device is in Continuum mode.